# IDE for remote Linux C++ code editing and debugging

Tags: linux, c++, ide

In Windows, an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for debugging and code editing at once is widely used. For example, Visual Studio and its debugger.

In Linux, there are several IDEs such as Visual Studio Code for code editing and debugging. Visual Studio Code, however, is for local Linux, i.e. Linux where desktop GUI module is included.

Unfortunately, on Linux server programming, most Linux machines have no GUI module in them. So Visual Studio Code or other local-machine-only IDE cannot be used.

In remote Linux, is there any popular IDE? AFAIK there are several IDEs which support remote Linux such as [VisualGDB](https://visualgdb.com/), [Visual Studio with Linux support](https://docs.microsoft.com/ko-kr/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project?view=vs-2019), but it seems that they lack of several functionalities such as code profiling or core dump.

Can you recommend me IDE softwares for remote Linux C++ coding and debugging easily?

Comment: Your best bet is to turn Vim or Emacs into an IDE by adding tons of plugins. Both of these editors can run from the command line and over SSH. Really, though, you revamp your workflow so that you don't need to modify C++ on your servers. Most reasonable workflows involve development on a local machine, then transferring compiled binaries or source to the target servers. Why do you need to do development on the servers themselves?

Comment: @markasoftware Is this one of what you say? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSNhTH1Co4

Comment: Both [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source) support cross-compiling and cross-debugging.